# Decode iso-8859-1 Characters in C#

Tags: c#, string, decode, iso-8859-1

I know this question have been asked before but I still can't get any answers I find to work.

For example i have this string:

```
string myString = "Betrakta nedanst&aring;ende figur";
```

And i want to decode it to:

```
string myString = "Betrakta nedanstående figur";
```

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you have shown has strictly nothing to do with the ISO-8859-1 encoding. It's just a string containing HTML encoded entities. To decode it you could use the [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function:

```
string myString = "Betrakta nedanst&aring;ende figur";
string myDecodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myString);
```

Note that you will need to reference the `System.Web` assembly in order to use that method.

Comment: Thanks! That explains why I had so much trouble finding the right answear :)